# How to replace all special characters with another character in java?

Tags: java, regex, csv

I want to replace all 'special characters' with a special character in java

For example 'cash&carry' will become 'cash+carry' and also 'cash$carry' will become 'cash+carry'

I have a sample CSV file as

Here the CSV headers are 'What' and 'Where'

```
What,Where
salon,new+york+metro
pizza,los+angeles+metro
crate&barrel,los+angeles+metro
restaurants,los+angeles+metro
gas+station,los+angeles+metro
persian+restaurant,los+angeles+metro
car+wash,los+angeles+metro
book store,los+angeles+metro
garment,los+angeles+metro
"cash,carry",los+angeles+metro
cash&carry,los+angeles+metro
cash carry,los+angeles+metro
```

The expected output

```
What,Where
salon,new+york+metro
pizza,los+angeles+metro
crate+barrel,los+angeles+metro
restaurants,los+angeles+metro
gas+station,los+angeles+metro
persian+restaurant,los+angeles+metro
car+wash,los+angeles+metro
book+store,los+angeles+metro
garment,los+angeles+metro
cash+carry,los+angeles+metro
cash+carry,los+angeles+metro
cash+carry,los+angeles+metro
```

The sample code is as follows

```
String csvfile="BidAPI.csv"; 

 try{

        // create the 'Array List'
        ArrayList<String> What=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Where=new ArrayList<String>();

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        StringTokenizer st=null;
        String line="";
        int linenumber=0;
        int columnnumber;
        int free=0;
        int free1=0;    

        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            linenumber++;
            columnnumber=0;

            st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                columnnumber++;
                String token=st.nextToken();
                if("What".equals(token)){
                    free=columnnumber;
                    System.out.println("the value of free  :"+free);
                    } else if("Where".equals(token)){
                    free1=columnnumber;
                    System.out.println("the value of free1 :"+free1);
                    } 

                    if(linenumber>1){

                if (columnnumber==free){
                    What.add(token);    
                } else if(columnnumber==free1){
                    Where.add(token);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // converting the  'What' Array List to array
    String[] what=What.toArray(new String[What.size()]);

    // converting the 'Where' Array List to array
    String[] where = Where.toArray(new String[Where.size()]);

    for(int i=0;i<what.length;i++){
    String data = what[i].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\",]| (?!([^\"]*\"){2}[^\"]*$)", "+").replace("\"", "");
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println(where[i]);
    String finaldata = data+where[i];
    String json = readUrl(desturl);
    br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("There is an error :"+e);
    }
```

All the special characters, all the spaces and the double quotes should be removed and replaced as in the desired output.

I am using `value.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "+")` , but it is not working.

Error

```
 cash
 carry"
```

Any help is appreciated. new to regex.

Comment: What is not working? What's your current output and why is it wrong?

Comment: @Robin : for example 'book store' remains 'book store' and it does not change.

Comment: Are you reassigning result of replaceAll to some String reference? You need to know that Strings are immutable, which means they can't change, so methods like `replace` are not affecting original String, but creating new version of it and return it.

Comment: Also how would you expect `"cash,carry",los+angeles+metro` to become `cash+carry,los+angeles+metro`? You just decided to replace all non alphanumeric characters and space to be space so it will result in `+cash+carry++los+angeles+metro`.

Comment: @Pshemo That's what happened and it became +cash and carry escaped to the next line, due to comma how to take care of it, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *escaped to the next line*? I don't see any code which adds line separators like `\n` or `\r` so they shouldn't be placed in new line. I will need to see code which produces your problem because what you posted here shouldn't be be able to create what you are describing.

Comment: Also it seems that you want to replace `,` only if they are inside quote. Is that true or some error in your example?

Comment: Are you replacing this text line by line, or is it entire string which  you want to edit with only one `replaceAll`? I am asking because I don't know if there are line separators inside your String.

Comment: @Pshemo : posted the code for reference. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

- replace all commas within quotes with +
- replace non-whitelist (and you need to add commas to your whitelist)
  +
- *remove* double quotes

Try this:

```
line = line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\",]|,(?!(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)", "+").replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: @Braj actually it seems that OP want's to do it, but only if `,` is inside quotation. Rest of them should be untouched.

Comment: Tested the suggestion as String data = what[i].replace("\"", "").replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ,]", "+"); but did not work for book store

Comment: @user3188390 it doesn't work for book store because this answer contains space in regex used in `replaceAll`. But if you remove it you will get essentially same answer as Martijn`s.

Comment: Got the same answer as Martijn's but with the problem with "cash,carry" still persists.Thanks for help and any further suggestions.

Comment: @Pshemo didn't notice the quoted space issue. I think I've got it now

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex is pretty close. Add an exception for comma's as well and get rid of the space and you are good.

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
{
    String replaced = line.replace("\"", "");
    replaced = replaced.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9,]", "+");
    System.out.println(replaced);
}
```

Of course, Strings are immutable in Java. Keep that in mind. `replaceAll()` returns a new String and does **not** modify the original instance.

[**Demo here.**](http://ideone.com/xIBd8O)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then how to replace "cash,carry" with cash+carry. I appreciate your help, and it is escaping to the next line, because of comma.

Comment: The OP replaced a space in the example by a +.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed. Was confused based on regex from question.

Comment: Posted the code for reference, also made the changes as suggested , but it throws error for "cash,carry" also posted the error.

Comment: Tested it but it still throws the error as cash and carry escapes to the next line

Answer (score 1):

You need to first find quote and replace `,` inside it with `+`. Next you can just use `replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9,]", "+")` so you will replace all non alphanumeric characters or `,` with `+`. Your code for that can use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
```

pattern to locate quotations and `appendReplacement`, `appendTail` from Matcher class to replace founded quotations with its new version.

So in short your code can look something like

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(csvfile));

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()){//find quotes
        //and replace their content with content with replaced `,` by `+`
        //BTW group(1) holds part of quotation without `"` marsk
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).replace(',', '+'));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);//we need to also add rest of unmatched data to buffer

    //now we can just normally replace special characters with +
    String result = sb.toString().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9,]", "+");

    //after job is done we can use result, so lest print it
    System.out.println(result);

    //lets not forget to reset buffer for next line
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and effort and I have tested the suggestion and it works fine, but what I am doing here is that I am matching the headers and then storing the data under each header as a token and adding it to an array list, so should I be writing the result to another CSV file and progress?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do with it later, so do what you think is right. I can't help you with that (especially since I never had a chance yet to work with CVS so my opinion may be wrong).

Comment: Got the answer used the code as suggested by @Bohemian and it worked. posting the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question

```
String csvfile="BidAPI.csv"; 

try{

    // create the 'Array List'
    ArrayList<String> What=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Where=new ArrayList<String>();

  BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
    StringTokenizer st=null;
    String line="";
    int linenumber=0;
    int columnnumber;
    int free=0;
    int free1=0;    

    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
         line =line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\",]|,(?!(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)", "+").replace("\"", "");
        linenumber++;
        columnnumber=0;

        st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            columnnumber++;
            String token=st.nextToken();
            if("What".equals(token)){
                free=columnnumber;
                System.out.println("the value of free  :"+free);
                } else if("Where".equals(token)){
                free1=columnnumber;
                System.out.println("the value of free1 :"+free1);
                } 

                if(linenumber>1){

            if (columnnumber==free){
                What.add(token);    
            } else if(columnnumber==free1){
                Where.add(token);
            }
        }
    }
}


// converting the  'What' Array List to array
String[] what=What.toArray(new String[What.size()]);

// converting the 'Where' Array List to array
String[] where = Where.toArray(new String[Where.size()]);

for(int i=0;i<what.length;i++){
String data = what[i].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\",]| (?!([^\"]*\"){2}[^\"]*$)", "+").replace("\"", "");
System.out.println(data);
System.out.println(where[i]);
String finaldata = data+where[i];
String json = readUrl(desturl);
br.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("There is an error :"+e);
}
```